# How would I go about hiding text under a moving picture

Tags: html, css

So I have code to move an image out of view when hovering over it's container but what I would like to do is have text under the image during the entire time and then have that text revealed as the image slides off to the side. How would I go about positioning the text under the image?

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/ff9ovhvp/6/

```css
.row {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  transition: 3.5s;
}
.imgHold:hover>img {
  transform: translateX(500px);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="imgHold">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x100">
    <h3>
          Some text here
        </h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use positioning to place the text behind the image, relative on the container and absolute on the h3:

```css
.row {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  transition: 3.5s;
}
.imgHold:hover>img {
  transform: translateX(500px);
}
.imgHold {
  position: relative;
}
.imgHold h3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.imgHold img {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="imgHold">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x100">
    <h3>
      Some text here
    </h3>
  </div>
</div>
```